# How do I read options from a jqgrid instance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I need to read the editurl from one jqgrid for use in a DND operation.

Background:

I have two jqgrid objects setup and have enabled drag and drop between the grids.  In the onDrop event handler, i have the incoming event handler for which i can get the id of the destition grid and the row data, but I need to submit an ajax post against the same url as the destination grid. (it has a querystring parameter i need to get to)

When you create a jqgrid object, you pass in a hash of options.  How do you get them back out of that object later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From "Methods" in [jQgrid wiki docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods&s%5B%5D=getgridparam):

```
var options=  $(tableSelector).jqGrid('getGridParam');
console.log(options)
```

To target a specific param:

```
var records=$("#gridId").getGridParam("records");
```

Comment: @LucasHolt: One can see that you not yet used voting which is very important for stackoverflow. You have right to vote up about 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) you find simple rule: "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." You should understand that voting are used by searching engine. So if you want help other visitors of the page you should use your voting right like I did now.